# 2008 buick lucerne CXL 3.8 L engine mounts

Tags: engine, alignment

I just got this car and a mechanic told me it needed a transmission mount on the drivers side.

After replacing it and saw that it wasn't bad I found the engine still moves a lot when power braking forward and in reverse.

I found the front lower engine mount was bad so I replaced it as well. Now the engine is tight but it has a lot of vibration when putting it in any gear at idle.

Is there an alignment procedure I have to do or should I be looking at the rear lower mount and possibly the top passenger dog bone mount which looks good?

Also are the lower engine mounts filled with oil for a cushion because I had a lot of oil pouring out of the front mount when I replaced it.

Comment: No alignment should be necessary, are the spark plugs good?

Comment: When was it last serviced?

Comment: Moab the engine ran smooth and fine before I changed these mounts.

Solar Mike I service all my fleet of vehicles and I assure you there's no miss nor engine roughness. This is like the engine is mounted solid instead of on rubber.